# Central division algebras over $ \mathbb{Q} $

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, noncommutative-algebra, class-field-theory, brauer-groups

Quaternions over $ \mathbb{Q} $ are an example of a Central  Division algebra over $\mathbb{Q} $ for which the basis elements $\{ i,j,ij \} $ other than $1$ are represented by skew-symmetric matrices in regular representation.

What are the other examples of Central divison algebras over $\mathbb{Q} $ with the same property? Are there any such examples with even dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$ other than $ 4 $ .

Comment: You find a complete classification (by Brauer invariant) in the book Assiciative Algebras by R.S. Pierce.

Comment: But @Zero I cant find  any example  of central divison algebras  over $\mathbb{Q} $ with such properties other than Quaternion  and octonions